# Kentico 13 - write to ViewContext from inlinewidgetpage

Tags: kentico

I am using DevTrev's [PartialWidgetPage](https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/PartialWidgetPage) to recreate the MasterPage functionality of previous Kentico versions.

The Nav and Footer get rendered into the `_Layout.cshtml` as expected but I have another component/widget in the master page that uses a `HtmlHelper` extension to write to `_Layout.cshtml` in a similar way to to `@RenderSection()` does.

The widget works fine when it is placed in a normal page but when it's in a page rendered by  the `PartialWidgetPage`, it doesn't get written to `_Layout.cshtml`.

The helper extension is as follows:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public static HtmlString AddResource(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, PageResourceType resourceType, string identifier, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
    {
        httpContextAccessor = Service.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] != null)
        {
            ((List<(Func<object, HelperResult>, string)>)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[resourceType]).Add((template, identifier));
        }
        else
        {
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] = new List<(Func<object, HelperResult>, string)>() { (template, identifier) };
        }

        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }

    public static HtmlString RenderResources(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, PageResourceType resourceType)
    {
        httpContextAccessor = Service.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[resourceType] != null)
        {
            List<(Func<object, HelperResult>, string)> resources = (List<(Func<object, HelperResult>, string)>)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[resourceType];

            foreach (var resource in resources.DistinctBy(r => r.Item2))
            {
                if (resource.Item1 != null)
                {
                    htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(resource.Item1(null));
                }
            }
        }

        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

And is called in `_Layout.cshtml` like so:

```
@Html.RenderResources(PageResourceType.HeadScript)
```

Comment: Sorry for late responses so this, but can i ask the question what you're trying to accomplish with this special widget?  I wonder if there's a simpler way to go about it...

Comment: @TrevorF Hi Trevor, this widget allows the editors to place scripts (eg GTM) on the "master page". In the end I added fields to my Master Page Page Type where the editors can place the script as there's no need for it to be a widget.

Comment: That's a much better solution! Also Sean write made an extension to help inject stuff into sections from within view components, but you can't have that in cache tags anywhere, so usually either page type property or custom settings work best.